# Trigger another pipeline and set variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline. The pipeline has a variable for the different environments. Now instead of copy the pipeline in three I would like to have a single pipeline the three other pipelines starts with a specific variable. When the pipelines calling the master pipeline has finished the releases should then be called for each. Is this possible with yaml and pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to end up with just two pipeline where the second is parameterized you may have an issue to pass that variable. A perfect match seems to be [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script). You may pass those parameters using [REST API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). This is sample example how you may run REST API from pipeline

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)?api-version=5.1"
    $build = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:MY_SECRET"}
    Write-Host "Pipeline = $($build | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

    $status = $build.status
    Write-Host $status
  name: initial
  env: 
    MY_SECRET: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Note: this call different endpoint than the one mentioned above.

However I would recommend you [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops). You may use this to extract common part and pass paramaters so it seems that it suits your case.

**template**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: name
  type: string
  default: 'lambdaNumbertOneFunctionName'
- name: arn
  type: string
  default: 'lambdaNumberOneFunctionArn'
- name: stepName
  type: string
  default: 'StepOne'
- name: value
  type: string
  default: 'testValue'

steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ parameters.name }};isOutput=true]${{ parameters.value }}"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ parameters.arn }};isOutput=true]${{ parameters.value }}"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Test;isOutput=true]${{ parameters.value }}"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Test2;isOutput=true]Yesy2"
  name: ${{ parameters.stepName }}

- script: |
    echo $(${{ parameters.stepName }}.${{ parameters.name }})
    echo $(${{ parameters.stepName }}.${{ parameters.arn }})
    echo $(${{ parameters.stepName }}.Test)
    echo $(${{ parameters.stepName }}.Test2)
```

**main file**

```yaml
  steps:
  - template: template.yaml
    parameters:
      name: 'lambdaNumbertOneFunctionName'
      arn: 'lambdaNumberOneFunctionArn'
      value: 'value-1'
      stepName: 'StepOne'
  - template: template.yaml
    parameters:
      name: 'lambdaNumberTwoFunctionName'
      arn: 'lambdaNumberTwoFunctionArn'
      value: 'value-2'
      stepName: 'StepTwo'
```

And templates you can use it in thre ways:

- define all three parts as separate stages/jobs in your main build
- define all three parts as separate stages/jobs in your second build and then trigger it using pipeline [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- define three separate pipelines and tigger them using above mentioned pipeline trigger

Comment: Templates looks like what I am looking for. Can you add a variable to a template?

Comment: Yes this is possible, however I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. Can you consider upvoting my answer if it is helpful to you?

Comment: I have a pipeline that needs to do exactly the same for dev, test and prod. Only difference is setting a varibale to Dev, Test and Prod. Instead of having 3 full yaml files I would just have a single Pipeline doing the build. And then 3 pipelines that just calls this single pipeline, but with 3 different variables. Does this make sense?